# Using for_each to increment array elements?

Tags: c++, std

Say I have the following:

```
int a[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
int x = something;
```

It is possible to use `for_each` to increment the elements of the array by x? I was thinking of something like:

```
for_each(a, a + 5, [](int& item) { item += x; });
```

But as far as I understand, the third parameter in `for_each`is a unary function so there's no way to pass x into it.

Comment: You can _capture_ `x` by writing the lambda as `[x](int& item) { item += x; }`

Comment: Any particular reason for not using the traditional for/for-each loop?

Comment: `a, a + 5` -> `std::begin(a), std::end(a)`.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts That did it. Thanks!